# Get all users with role

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to get all users that have an role using discord.js.

`let roleFromID = message.guild.roles.cache.get(roleID)`

I need an array with every user with that role.
This is what I tried:
`var members = message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.roles.cache.find(role => role == roleFromID)).map(member => member.user.tag);`
But, it returns empty list. How to fix that?

Comment: `member.roles.cache.has(roleID)` should be sufficient.

Comment: I don't want to check every user if it has the role, but get all users that have the role

Comment: Right.. so `message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.roles.cache.has(roleID))`...

Comment: aand it still return empty list ( [] ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use [Role.members](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=members).
This returns a collection of members with the role.

```js
const role = await message.guild.roles.fetch('role-id');
await message.guild.members.fetch();
const { members } = role //Collection of members
```

Comment: It returns the collection only if bot has the role specified, if bot doesn't have the role it just gives empty collection

Comment: Do `message.guild.roles.fetch(<RoleResolvable>)` then

Comment: Once a guild is cached, it's roles will also be cached, no need to fetch a role

Comment: @Viriato it is not `RoleResolvable` as the first parameter, it needs the ID

Comment: @MrMythical Error [GUILD_MEMBERS_TIMEOUT]: Members didn't arrive in time.

Comment: You have to enable guild members intent

Comment: What? What is that? And how to enable it

Comment: What? What's that? And how to enable it?

Comment: It’s in Discord Developer Portal.

Comment: it works pretty but it returns all members on server

Comment: Do all of them have the role? Can you share exactly how you put it in the variable according to this code?

Comment: Only some members have the role, but it anyways returns all members. I'm doing forEach  and printing usernames into console.

Comment: Can you edit that new code into the question?

Comment: @MrMythical `<RoleResolvable>` can be a Snowflake (role ID). Although this doesn't apply to the question in discussion, like @Elitezen said guild roles are cached by default.

Comment: It doesn’t accept the role resolvable though. It only accepts the ID

Comment: @MrMythical sorry I've put wrong variable in ```.fetch('role-id');```, now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```js
msg.guild.members.cache.filter(member=>member.roles.cache.find(role=>role.id==roleID))//.forEach(m=>{console.log(m.user.username)})
```

Comment: It returns the collection only if bot has the role specified, if bot doesn't have the role it just gives empty collection

Comment: oh, sorry now it says `undefined`