# Listing users who has specific roles (discord.js v12)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to list all users who have a specific role. I am trying to list the number of users who have that role and the users who have the role.

Error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of null`

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "list",
    description: "Lists all users with roles",
    async execute(message, client, args) {
        let roleName = message.content.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ");

        if (!roleName) return message.channel.send("Please mention or provide a role ID.");

        message.guild.members.fetch().then((members) => {
            let membersWithRole = members
                .filter((mmbr) => mmbr.roles.cache.get(roleName))
                .map((m) => m.user.tag)
                .join("\n");

            const sizes = message.guild.roles.resolve(roleName).members.size;

            const embed1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle(`Users with ${roleName} (${sizes})`) // Users with RoleX, (1 users)
                .setDescription(membersWithRole) //
                .setColor("RANDOM");

            message.channel.send(embed1);
        });
    },
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all users with role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68593981/get-all-users-with-role)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`RoleManager#resolve`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=resolve) accepts a [`RoleResolvable`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/RoleResolvable) ([`Role`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role), [`Snowflake`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/Snowflake)), not a name. You'll have to try and find the [`Role`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role) by name.

---

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "list",
    description: "Lists all users with roles",
    async execute(message, client, args) {
        const role = message.mentions.roles.first() ? message.mentions.roles.first() : message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === message.content.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ") || role.id === message.content.split(" ").slice(1).join(" "));
        if (!role) return message.channel.send("Please mention or provide a role ID.");

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`Users with ${role.name} (${role.members.size})`)
            .setDescription(role.members.map(member => member.user.tag).join(', '))
            .setColor("RANDOM");
        message.channel.send(embed)
    },
};
```

*Note that [`Role`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role) has a property called [`members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=members), so you don't have to fetch all of the members and check if each of them has the role.*